# How much would the orbit of the earth change if we launched all 'garbage' into outer space

Tags: cosmology, orbital-motion

I know it's not economically feasible, but is there a simple equation telling you the ellipse earth would follow if you theoretically launch all of the landfills, i.e. garbage, beyond our orbit, thus decreasing mass by X.

Comment: That would depend on the launch direction. One could, for instance, launch this mass in such a way ("symmetrically"), that the orbit of the planet wouldn't change, at all. Moreover, by how much an orbit changes, depends on the location at the time of the momentum transfer, and spacecraft orbits are changed at specific points, e.g. apogee or perigee to achieve the required new orbit with the least expense of propellant. Do you have a particular change of orbit in mind? I think that would make the question better defined in terms of how one would use this mass to achieve the orbital change.

Comment: If you launched the rockets at the right times, them you could balance out the changes so that there would be very little effect on the orbit.

Comment: I was more thinking about the loss of mass of the earth rather than the rocket acceleration.